# Two onchange events where the second event grabs the value of the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **one combobox** and **two textboxes** and when the value changes of the combobox I query data for **textbox one** and send it to the page via post. The same happens for this **second textbox** but it is relying on the value of the first textbox. Both of these textboxes are changed when the combobox is changed. I tried making the second textbox change on the first textbox but nothing shows up when that is the case.

My code is as follows:

```
//Fetch Value for Textbox 1 and post to page

            $('#combobox').change(function(){    
            var cs = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val(); 
            var pj = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val(); 
            var vd = $('#combobox').val();  
            var data_String;
             data_String = 'cs='+cs+'&pj='+pj+'&vd='+vd;
             $.post('ft-numbervendorpo.php',data_String,function(data){
                   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#textbox1').val(data);
                });

                $('#textbox1').val('');
                  $('#textbox2').val('');
            });

//Fetch value for Textbox 2 and post to page

            $('#combobox').change(function(){
            var countpre = $('#textbox2').val();
            var p = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val();
            var c = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val();
            var v = $('#combobox').val();
            var cp = (parseInt(countpre)+1);
            var data_String;
             data_String = 'p='+p+'&c='+c+'&v='+v+'&cp='+cp;
             $.post('ft-final-v-po-num.php',data_String,function(data){
                   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                   $('#textbox2').val(data);
                });
            });
```

When I change `$('#combobox').change(function(){` to `$('#textbox1').change(function(){` for **textbox 2** nothing comes up. Currently, with the way the code is above, the output is `#####-##-##-NaN`. Where `#` are varying numbers. The desired output is `#####-##-##-('#textbox1' + 1)`. I don't know if a wait function would hurt the performance on my page but I don't see it as ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put the code to fill the second textbox in the same event as the first, just wrap it in the `.done`

```
$('#combobox').change(function(){    
     var cs = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val(); 
     var pj = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val(); 
     var vd = $('#combobox').val();  
     var data_String;
     data_String = 'cs='+cs+'&pj='+pj+'&vd='+vd;
     $.post('ft-numbervendorpo.php',data_String,function(data){
         var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         $('#textbox1').val(data);
      }).done(function() {
         var countpre = $('#textbox2').val();
         var p = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val();
         var c = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val();
         var v = $('#combobox').val();
         var cp = (parseInt(countpre)+1);
         var data_String;
         data_String = 'p='+p+'&c='+c+'&v='+v+'&cp='+cp;
         $.post('ft-final-v-po-num.php',data_String,function(data){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               $('#textbox2').val(data);
         });
      });

      $('#textbox1').val('');
      $('#textbox2').val('');
});
```

Or you can use the success option from the first POST request to fire the second POST request

```
$('#combobox').change(function(){    
     var cs = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val(); 
     var pj = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val(); 
     var vd = $('#combobox').val();  
     var data_String;
     data_String = 'cs='+cs+'&pj='+pj+'&vd='+vd;
     $.post('ft-numbervendorpo.php',data_String,function(data){
         var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         $('#textbox1').val(data);
         var countpre = $('#textbox2').val();
         var p = $('#irrelevantcombobox').val();
         var c = $('#irrelevantcombobox2').val();
         var v = $('#combobox').val();
         var cp = (parseInt(countpre)+1);
         var data_String;
         data_String = 'p='+p+'&c='+c+'&v='+v+'&cp='+cp;
         $.post('ft-final-v-po-num.php',data_String,function(data){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               $('#textbox2').val(data);
         });
      });

      $('#textbox1').val('');
      $('#textbox2').val('');
});
```

I would suggest, however, if you are using a new enough version (which looking at your code you probably do) of jQuery (at least  jQuery 1.5) that you use the `.done(function(){});` structure to ensure that the post is completed before you call the second one.

As a side note and from personal experience. I use the `.done` a lot in my jQuery code and I do not really notice a performance hit that is physically discernible (i.e. the page takes 101 ms (with the `.done`) vs 99 ms (without the `.done`).

Comment: Awesome answer! I never knew about `.done` this works flawlessly.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help, and pay it forward. I first learned about `.done` on this site and it has revolutionized the way I code my jQuery ajax, post, and get calls